# Vue Table with draggable rows won't get exported reordered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

High I'm new at programming in Vue, but I want to use Vue Leaflet. So I made thiggs simplified version of my program which highlights a major programming problem I have.

**The code**
See link: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-shadow-xpxzww?file=/index.html

**The goal**
To make a table 
1.  with draggable rows
2.  with data which can be imported
3.  with data which can be added and removed 
4.  And then the data can be reordered
5. And then export the data
6. And do it all in html and js
**What I have done so far**
I had no problems with everything except for number 4. I tried vue.draggable, however I could not get it to reorder at all. So I used the HTML Drag and Drop API (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp). When you select a row, the first column will restart with counting the indices from top to bottom. But that leads to the problem.

**The problem**
My code doesn't have a function or method which sends info about the reordering of the rows to the save file function and I do not see how I can implement that. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dragover function so that it includes the array.splice function from this youtube clip from webdevtv: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syfUi_n-tv8

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).